# Why am I losing transparency when calling BitBlt or CopyRect?

Tags: delphi, lazarus

**Problem**

I am trying to copy 32x32 tiles from a `TBitmap` into a `TPaintbox` which is my map editor, but I cannot seem to get the transparency working correctly.

**See the image below:**

*Note: For the purpose of the demo and testing, I have placed a TImage underneath the TPaintbox which would help see if the transparency is working or not.*

[image]

As you can see, regular tiles draw correctly, but the tiles that should be transparent are drawn with a white background.

I am now using proper classes to manage my maps and tiles, and below is two ways I have tried drawing:

*CopyRect:*

```
procedure TMap.DrawTile(Tileset: TBitmap; MapX, MapY, TileX, TileY: Integer;
  MapCanvas: TCanvas);
begin
  if TileIsFree(MapX, MapY) then
  begin
    MapCanvas.CopyRect(
      Rect(MapX, MapY, MapX + fTileWidth, MapY + fTileHeight),
      Tileset.Canvas,
      Rect(TileX, TileY, TileX + fTileWidth, TileY + fTileHeight));
  end;
end;
```

*BitBlt*

```
procedure TMap.DrawTile(Tileset: TBitmap; MapX, MapY, TileX, TileY: Integer;
  MapCanvas: TCanvas);
begin
  if TileIsFree(MapX, MapY) then
  begin
    BitBlt(
      MapCanvas.Handle,
      MapX,
      MapY,
      fTileWidth,
      fTileHeight,
      Tileset.Canvas.Handle,
      TileX,
      TileY,
      SRCCOPY);
  end;
end;
```

I have tried using bitmap and png image formats for the tileset (left image on the screenshot). The only difference between bitmap and png is that `CopyRect` struggles to draw even a few tiles when it is a png, but `BitBlt` manages to draw without any obvious drawbacks.

Anyway, how do I copy/draw part of a `TBitmap` onto a `TPaintbox` without losing transparency, or in my case without also copying the white background?

**Update 1**

Following on from some of the comments below I have tried calling the `AlphaBlend` function but this still leaves undesirable results (note the blue colors around  the transparent areas):

```
procedure TMap.DrawTile(Tileset: Graphics.TBitmap; MapX, MapY, TileX, TileY: Integer;
  MapCanvas: TCanvas);
var
  BlendFn: TBlendFunction;
begin
  if TileIsFree(MapX, MapY) then
  begin
    BlendFn.BlendOp := AC_SRC_OVER;
    BlendFn.BlendFlags := 0;
    BlendFn.SourceConstantAlpha := 255;
    BlendFn.AlphaFormat := AC_SRC_ALPHA;

    AlphaBlend(
      MapCanvas.Handle,
      MapX,
      MapY,
      fTileWidth,
      fTileHeight,
      Tileset.Canvas.Handle,
      TileX,
      TileY,
      fTileWidth,
      fTileHeight,
      BlendFn);
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: BitBlt, StretchBlt (CopyRect) does not have transparency support. Use Canvas.Draw.

Comment: Or [`TransparentBlt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145141.aspx)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am looking at `TransparentBlt` right now... Lazarus seems to hate adding the unit: `JwaWinGDI` though to the uses as it messes up other types like TBitmap, so I am having to declare standard types like `Graphics.TBitmap` etc.

Comment: @Blobby: The same problem occurs in Delphi when using the `Windows` unit, because the `Windows.TBitmap` record is different than the `Graphics.TBitmap` class.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for letting me know. I dont even think I have the correct unit, the last parameter for `TransparentBlt` expects a RGB Color according to the Windows API link you posted, yet in Lazarus the last parameter is `BlendFunction`, so I cannot figure out what to put in for the last parameter.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I must be missing something obvious here :) I know how to use `Canvas.Draw` but I need a way to specify the X,Y position of the source graphic to copy. Right now I have: `MapCanvas.Draw(MapX, MapY, Tileset);` but I need something like: `MapCanvas.Draw(MapX, MapY, TileX, TileY, Tileset);` = where TileX, and TileY would be the X,Y position of the source graphic. I could copy to a local declared `TBitmap` but as Remy Lebeau pointed out to me the other day in a different question it would slow the painting down significantly.

Comment: @Blobby - Yes, using a temporary bitmap might effect performance.

Comment: I have successfully used `AlphaBlend()` for similar drawing. That also requires a BlendFunction parameter. It is explained in MSDN.

Comment: Have a look to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21849074) for few alternatives, including AlphaBlend Rudy mentioned.

Comment: `AlphaBlend` does not seem to be working as I had hoped so will try `TransparentBlt` and see if I can use the BlendFunction in the same way..

Comment: `TransparentBlt` is worse than `AlphaBlend` unless I am defining something wrong. Have even tried with various tileset images that I know are 100% transparent.

Comment: `TransparentBlt` should work just fine. The first five parameters are the destination DC (your map) and the location and size of where to draw. The second five parameters are the source DC (your tile) and the location and size of what to draw. The last parameter is the color (not `TColor` but `TColorRef`, see `ColorToRGB` (in Delphi)) that the routine should consider transparent: those pixels won't be copied from the source to the destination. It seems like white would do for you. If there's white that does need to be copied, adjust one of its RGB values just with 1: e.g. 255-255-254.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 popular ways to work with transparent bitmaps, first two use standard Delphi tools and the third one requires a third-party library:

If you use one of the two standard methods, don’t use BitBlt or CopyRect. Use the Draw method of the transparent image holder to draw on destination canvas.

1. Keep your transparent bitmaps in a TImageList and use TImageList.Draw to paint directly on destination canvas (don’t paint on intermediary bitmaps since you will lose transparency here). To add images to an image list at design time, right click and choose Image List Editor.  Images in the list may be bitmaps, icons, PNG, GIF and JPEG images: any image type that TImage supports. ImageLists also support 32-bit format, so alpha blended bitmaps and PNG files work properly. You can also load images at run time. If your bitmaps are stored in a non-transparent form but there is a transparent color, you can use the TImageList.AddMasked(Bitmap: TBitmap; MaskColor: TColor) method. You can either pass the transparent color yourself in the second parameter or clDefault to let the imagelist take the bottom-left pixel's color.
2. Keep your images in PNG files or resources and load them into a Vcl.Imaging.pngimage.TpngImage, then call TpngImage.Draw to paint your PNG directly on destination canvas. As above, don’t paint on intermediary bitmaps since you will lose transparency here.
3. Use TBitmap32 from GR32, a third-party library. In this case, Do not use TBitmap32 with transparent images to draw directly on HDC, Canvas or TBitmap. Use dmBlend and DrawTo or BlockTransfer() to draw on another TBitmap32. For example, to draw transparently on a TBitmap, create an intermediary cache TBitmap32: (1) Copy the image from TBitmap to the cache TBitmap32; (2) Apply your transparent image to the cache TBitmap32 using DrawTo or BlockTransfer(), avoid using Canvas or HDC to mix two images because they lose alpha layer information; (3) Copy the image back from the cache TBitmap32 to your TBitmap.